# Mysql join 3 tables query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like following:

```
branch
id   name
---------
1    abc
2    xyz

users
id branch_id name
-----------------
1  1         aa
2  1         bb
3  2         cc
4  1         dd
5  2         ee

sales

id user_id product  price
1   1      xxxx     10
2   1      yyyy     20
3   2      zzzz     18
4   3      aaaa     12
5   2      bbbb     10
6   4      cccc     20
```

Now I want to get the total selling amount branch wise like:

```
branch_id total_price
---------------------
1         78     
2         12
```

For that i write a sql query like:

```
SELECT SUM(s.price) , b.id
FROM sales s
JOIN branch b
GROUP BY id
HAVING s.user_id
IN (
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE branch_id = b.id
)
```

But this does not provide the answer that I want. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT  branch.id AS branch_id, SUM(s.price) AS total_price
FROM branch
JOIN users  ON branch.id = users.branch_id
JOIN sales ON users.id = sales.user_id
GROUP BY branch.id;
```

Also you could use `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`(Both are doing the same thing). With `INNER JOIN` it is possibly easier to read, especially your query contains other types of `JOIN`'s like `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please, inform OP that INNER JOIN is the same as JOIN. The INNER keyword is optional. As it is now OP may think it's two different ways to join.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for your advice. Thats what i wanted to say with "Also you could use INNER JOIN instead of join."! But it seems like its not formulated that good.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT u.branch_id, SUM(s.price) AS total_price
FROM sales AS s INNER JOIN users u ON s.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY u.branch_id
ORDER BY u.branch_id
```